# Как обращатья к ресурсам через İntent

Tags: listview, android-intent, getview

Eсть Активити c `Listview`, в котором списки состоят из трех `textview`, и одного `imgview`.

Один из `textview`- это вступления биографии. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на список через `onİtemClick` я передавал с помощью интента текст из `string-array`. Там я заранее прописал 10 полных биографий.

Как сделать, чтобы я вызывал для нужного списка нужный текст? Ведь списки позиционируются авто. Если можно, исходник с примером.

Как `intent` соединить со списком `listview`, и чтобы `intent` сам по порядку клал тексты с 1 по 10 в зависимости от нажатого списка?